# Let $M(n,\mathbb R)$ denote set of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb R$.Which are true:

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M(n,\mathbb R)$ denote set of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb R$.Which are true:

1.If $A\in M(2,\mathbb R)$ is nilpotent and non-zero ,then there exists a matrix $B\in M(2,\mathbb R)$ such that $B^2=A$

2.If $A\in M(n,\mathbb R)$ is symmetric  and positive definite  ,then there exists a symmetric matrix $B\in M(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $B^2=A$

3.If $A\in M(n,\mathbb R)$ is symmetric  ,then there exists a symmetric matrix $B\in M(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $B^3=A$

I dont know how to approach these?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints to get you started.

1. If $A$ is nilpotent and $B^2 = A$, what can you say about higher powers of $B$? And which power of $A$ is guaranteed to give you the zero matrix?
2. Think about diagonalizing $A$. Can you compute a square root of a diagonal matrix?
3. Think about diagonalizing $A$. Can you compute a cube root of a diagonal matrix?

Comment: what is meant by cube root or square root of a matrix?can u please elaborate

Comment: for the first part $A^2=0$

Comment: $B$ is a square root of $A$ if $B^2 = A$.

Comment: I managed to come up with a counter-example for part (a) but couldn't proceed in the other two parts. Would you kindly post a complete solution?

Answer (score 0):

1. If A is $\begin{bmatrix}{0}&{1}\\{0}&{0}\end{bmatrix}$ clearly ${A}{A}=0$ and you can  prove that is a counterexample.